# Nilpotence of a linear endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

Let $F$  be a field, $V$ a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space and $f \in \operatorname{End}_{F}(V)$.

Show: If $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb {C}$ and there is no one-dimensional subspace  $U$ of $V$ with $ f(U)=U$, then $f$ nilpotent.

Proof:
We have to show that there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n = 0$.

Let $v \in U$ be an eigenvector to the eigenwert $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. Since $f(U)=U$ we know that $U$ is invariant and $f^n(v)=\lambda^n v \ \forall v \in U$

Now, how to go from here? Is it true that $f \neq 0$ because of $dim(U) \neq 1$?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be careful using $U$ without a definition. There is no $U$ specified in the question; it simply says that there is no one-dimensional subspace of $V$ preserved by the map $f$. If you want to make reference to a $U$, you'll need to define it first!

Comment: Let me give you a hint. The kicker here is not that any $U$ with $f(U) = U$ would have to have higher than one dimension, the kicker is the equality $f(U) = U$, rather than the usual condition of invariance: $f(U) \subseteq U$. Complex vector spaces always have at least one eigenvalue/eigenvector pair, meaning there is at least one one-dimensional $U$ (spanned by the eigenvector) such that $f(U) \subseteq U$. In most cases, i.e. for most eigenvalues, this will result in $f(U) = U$, but there is one exception.

Comment: @TheoBendit I guess the exception is for 0 as an eigenvalue? So the next step is defining any $U$?

Comment: Defining $U$ is not really going to help. The point is, there is no such $U$. But, what you have shown is that there are no eigenvalues other than $0$. What does that tell you?

Comment: @TheoBendit So just from the fact that $f^n(v) = \lambda^n v$ and $f(U) = U$ I showed that $0$ is an eigenvalue hence my operator is nilpotent?

Comment: As Marc van Leeuwen says, a non-zero eigenvalue means a one-dimensional subspace $U$ (spanned by the eigenvector) such that $f(U) = U$, against assumption. So, only zero eigenvalues exist. Having $0$ as *an* eigenvalue does not mean nilpotence (it just means the endomorphism is singular), but we've shown that $0$ is the *only* eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An endomorphism of a finite dimensional complex vector space is nilpotent if and only if it has no nonzero eigenvalues. If you accept this general fact, then the claim becomes obvious, since an eigenvector with nonzero eigenvalue spans a subspace $U$ with $f(U)=U$.